# how to get the same value of fromdate into todate of calendar control

Tags: jquery

This is my design part I am using bootstrap calendar control

```
 <div class="row">
                            @*From date Control*@
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6" id="fromdate">

                                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">From Date</label>
                                <div class="col-xs-9 dateContainer">
                                    <div class="input-group input-append date dateContainer" id="startDatePicker">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="startDate" name="startDate" placeholder="Select From Date" />
                                        <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            @*To date Control*@
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6" id="enddate">

                                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">To Date</label>
                                <div class="col-xs-9 dateContainer">
                                    <div class="input-group input-append date dateContainer" id="endDatePicker">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endDate" name="endDate" placeholder="Select To Date" />
                                        <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

and my jquery code as:

```
$('#startDatePicker')
            .datepicker({
                format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
            })

        .on('changeDate', function (e) {
            //debugger;
            var startdate = $("#startDate", this).val();
            $('input[name="endDate"]').val(startdate);

            // Revalidate the start date field
            $('#frmAddTurnover').formValidation('revalidateField', 'startDate');
        });

        $('#endDatePicker')
            .datepicker({
                format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
            })
            .on('changeDate', function (e) {
                // Revalidate the end date field
                $('#frmAddTurnover').formValidation('revalidateField', 'endDate');
            });
```

Here I want to get the fromdate value  into todate.
I want the value of fromdate into todate with calendar of same.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setDate` function of datepicker:

```
...
var startdate = $("#startDate", this).val();
$('input[name="endDate"]').datepicker("setDate",startdate);
...
```

Comment: i have got a issue with conversion format.. like i have given 03-06-2010 in from date but in todate its getting as 06-03-2010

Comment: and the validation for fromdate and todate is not working @KAD